# node.js catalog search implementation

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

My issue is implement some simple search and dropdown suggestions from my web catalog. Something like that [image]

Now all my items stores in items.xml file , like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog_list>
    <catalog change_list="id,parent_id,title" status="new" id="13642">
        <id>13642</id>
        <parent_id>00001</parent_id>
        <title>ITEM1</title>
    </catalog>
    <catalog change_list="id,parent_id,title" status="new" id="13634">
        <id>13634</id>
        <parent_id>09851</parent_id>
        <title>ITEM2</title>
    </catalog>
    <catalog change_list="id,parent_id,title" status="new" id="13635">
        <id>13635</id>
        <parent_id>09851</parent_id>
        <title>ITEM3</title>
        </catalog>
......
```

where **parent_id** key refs to id from description.xml with description of item.
So I think parse all that files to my mongoDB (so I will have two corresponding tables), and use db in my item order page template(request for some fields with images, description , price and etc.) Maybe I am thinking very wrong, pls correct me.

But I dont know what to do with my search implementation, should I make response to my mongoDB every user key press (onkeyUp() event?It seems to me so ugly and slow. Maybe I can use some indexing libs for NODE.JS?

Comment: Yes you need a query to your DB or XML file for each search you want to do

Comment: you could optimize it by only looking though the last matches as they type. for example, anything that matched "free" will also have matched "fre" and "fr"...

Comment: The keyup event is good enough to handle this, but don't execute the handler on every keyup (i.e. return early), instead use a delay to wait for more keyup events and after that delay, if the query has changed, first  cancel any previously sent, not yet finished requests, then send the new request with the changed query.

Comment: How many items you do have ? and how much traffic do you have in peak ?

Comment: I have around 3000 items in my catalog, so  I need grab users input and comparing with  two values from my mongoDB : with name and with item uniqueId .